# JOIN 3 tabelas diferentes exibir lista

Tags: php, mysql, join

Bom Dia Pessoal.

Estou tentando joinar 3 tabelas e exibir em uma lista, mas não estou consguindo.
Eu desenhei (COM MENOS LINHAS) as tabelas no banco de dados e uma ideia de como estou tentando listar os campos.

[image: Tabelas no banco de dados e listagem]

Acredito que para isso eu deva fazer 3 joins, mas não está dando certo.

```
$i=0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payment 
LEFT JOIN booking ON payment.booking_id = booking.id 
LEFT JOIN customer ON booking.customer_id = customer.id
WHERE (date >= '$datainicialsql' AND date <= '$datafinalsql') ORDER BY date") or die(mysql_error());

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $contador = $i;
    $vcustomer = $linha["customer.name"];
    $vtype = $linha["type"];
    $vdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($linha["date"]));

    $vvalue = $linha["amount"];

    echo $i . $customer . " Name: $vcustomer" . " - " . " Date: $vdate" . " Type: $vtype" . " Date: $vdate" . " Amount: $vvalue" .  "<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi bem o que pretende o que falta é adicionar ao *SELECT* a coluna *name* da tabela *Customer*

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT customer.name, type, date, amount FROM payment 
LEFT JOIN booking ON payment.booking_id = booking.id 
LEFT JOIN customer ON booking.customer_id = customer.id
WHERE (date >= '$datainicialsql' AND date <= '$datafinalsql') ORDER BY date") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: É exatamente isso no SQL @ramaral. Rodando no phpmyadmin ficou perfeito. Vou ter que trocar o método que uso para exibir os dados de while para foreach também. Correto?

Comment: DaviRRossini, não existe a necessidade de mudar para foreach, basta alterar o a variável result presente no seu código para a informada pelo @ramaral.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Isso já entra no domínio do *PHP* que é algo que não domino.

Comment: Agradeço mais uma vez, já adicionei a variável e ficou perfeita a solução. Agora vou colocar em uma tabela para ficar mais bonito visualmente.